# Strange file permissions on FAT32 under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, file-permissions, fat32, ext4

On my machine (Lenovo ThinkPad w510, Ubuntu 10.10) I have (at least) two logical partitions:

- an ext4 partition to which Ubuntu is installed;
- a FAT32 partition (the bigger one) on which I store all my working data.

For some strange reason, the default file permissions on these partitions differ.

For example, when I download rebar from its [git repository](https://github.com/RJ/erlang_rebar_example_project), there is different behaviour after I do `git clone https://github.com/RJ/erlang_rebar_example_project.git`:

- on ext4 partition I just do `cd rebar && make` and it works;
- on FAT32 I can not do `make`, because all the files inside the cloned `rebar` folder have the following permission: `-rw-r--r--`. If I do `sudo chmod 777 -R rebar` the file permissions don't change.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`-rw-r--r--` isn't the real set of attributes. FAT32 only has `RHSA`, Read-Hidden-System-Archive. Ubuntu maps those to "similar" Unix attributes depending on mount options. You can explicitly set this mask with the `umask=` mount option. (There's also a `dmask` for directories only and `fmask` for files only).